# cp1251: encoding distortion when converting from char* to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, winapi, character-encoding, char, wchar-t

I have a Russian string, stored in cpp source file with cp1251 encoding.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const char *src = "Мой текст";
    wchar_t dst[30];

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        mbstowcs(dst, src, 29);
        //outputs "Ìîé òåêñò" instead of "Мой текст"
        MessageBox(hWnd, dst, L"Header", MB_OK);    
    ...
```

Unfortunately, "Мой текст" is distorted. Seems that `mbstowcs` shouldn't be used in this case, but what should I use?

Tried `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.cp1251");` at WinMain, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `MultiByteToWideChar`, it lets you specify the codepage explicitly.

Comment: Also, try `"ru-RU.cp1251"` for locale string (a dash, not an underscore). I suspect your `setlocale` call fails; check for that.

Comment: Or try `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian_Russia.1251")`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It didn't fail, but gave the same incorrect result.

Comment: @nwellnhof Surprisingly "Russian_Russia.1251" did the job! Thx.

Comment: why not have all text initially as `L"Мой текст"` in unicode format ? and not need convert in this case

Comment: The encoding of a *narrow* string literal like `"Мой текст"` is subject to the charset used to save the source file (unless you use the `u8` prefix to force UTF-8). That may be different than the charset that `mbstowcs()` uses at runtime. Like RbMm said, you should be using a *wide* string literal instead: `const wchar_t *src = L"Мой текст"; ... MessageBoxW(hWnd, src, L"Header", MB_OK);`

Comment: @RbMm Because in the real program I deal with a char* field of a class whose value is being read from a file, I cannot change this.

Comment: @user4035 - in this case use `MultiByteToWideChar(1251,..`

Comment: @RbMm Tried: `MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, src, 9, dst, 29);`, didn't work. What parameters should I use?

Comment: @RbMm Fount the solution: `MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, src, -1, dst, 29);`

Comment: @user4035 - dont know how you try (or may be you use different encoding for russian text) but this code work correct `void cc(PCSTR str)
{
 if (int len = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, MAXDWORD, 0, 0))
 {
  PWSTR wz = (PWSTR)alloca(len * sizeof(WCHAR));

  if (MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, MAXDWORD, wz, len))
  {
   MessageBoxW(0, wz, wz, 0);
  }
 }
}` cc("Мой текст");

Comment: @user4035 - *I deal with a char* field of a class whose value is being read from a file* - so you need hardcode string lengths but calculate it in runtime

Comment: @RbMm "you need hardcode string lengths but calculate it in runtime" - Yes

Comment: @user4035 - simply i always use winapi only, when you look like prefer c/c++ runtime api like mbstowcs

Comment: @nwellnhof: That changes the locale for *all* threads in the process, with unknown consequences. You should either (temporarily) change the locale of the calling thread only, or better yet, not touch the locale at all, and use conversion facilities that can take locale information as input.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point, using `MultiByteToWideChar` has less side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx), the format of the locale string is `language[_country_region[.code_page]]` where `code_page` is the number of the code page without "cp". The [table of supported languages and countries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx) lists "Russian" and "Russia", so the correct string for `setlocale` is `"Russian_Russia.1251"`.